# SQL Server 2005 - Stripping Only Alpha Values from String

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 and I want to extract the alpha part of a string.

i.e.

From `ABC123`, I would like to get `ABC`

From `AB1234`, I would like to get `AB`.
etc etc.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: what mix of data do you have? Eg only A-Z and 0-9? Punctuation? or letters, space, numbers as KM spotted?

Comment: no punctuation, just A-Z , 0-9.

Comment: is the pattern letters+digits or do you have strings like  any of the follwoing: `123ABC456` or `123ABC` or `ABC` or `123` or `A1B2C3`?

Comment: Always letters then digits i.e. XYZ123 or XZ321 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Always letters then digits i.e. XYZ123 or XZ321 etc – GordyII Mar 2
>   '10 at 0:26

I know this is an old post BUT... If the quote above is true, then this is easy...

```
 SELECT LEFT(YourStringColumn, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',YourStringColumn)-1)
   FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a user defined function that would loop through the characters and build up a new string where the characters were letters.

Comment: Pretty much it. Loop, numbers table, whatever. No fancy methods, really

Answer (score 1):

if there is always a space between the letter and the digits, try:

```
DECLARE @String  varchar(100)
SET @String='ABC 123'

SELECT LEFT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(' ',@String))
```

OUTPUT

```
-------------------
ABC

(1 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT** after OP's comment, assumes no space before digits:

```
DECLARE @String  varchar(100)
SET @String='ABCD123'

;with Numbers AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number,ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@String,1,1)) AS Digit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1,ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@String,Number+1,1)) AS Digit
        FROM Numbers
    WHERE Number<LEN(@String)
)
SELECT LEFT(@String,MAX(Number)) FROM Numbers WHERE Digit=0
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)  --if the string is longer than 100 characters uncomment this and set "n" to the string length
```

OUTPUT:

```
-------------------
ABCD

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Sorry, no spaces or defining characters.

Comment: @GordyII, then your question has **BAD** examples

Comment: @KM, NEVER ;-) use a recursive CTE to "count" like you did. Please see the following article for why... http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: @Jeff Moden, I see your point, but I'm only generating the numbers for the length of the given string, which is 7

Comment: Two things wrong with that answer, KM... 1) someone who finds your code will use it for something biigger and 2) like I said in my article, even such small numbers are relatively very poor compared to the other methods.  To wit, you've just spent more time justifying doing it wrong than it would have taken you to do it correctly. :-)

Comment: @Jeff Moden, congradulations! your answer from last year is clearly better to this two year old question.  Why keep commenting on it, move on, there are many new questions each day.  If anyone finds this question in the future, they will see your answer.  What about the other answers to this question, you didn't comment on them.

Answer (score 0):

You also might consider doing this not in SQL but somewhere else, if it is possible in your scenario. If you explain what kind of data are you working with how they get into your sql database and what and how uses them it might be possible to suggest a better alternative.